# Prove two topologies are the same

Tags: general-topology, topological-vector-spaces

Let  $\tau_1$ be the topology on $\mathbb{R}^2$ induced by the Euclidean norm.

We consoder the seminorms $\{s_k;\ k=1,2\}$ on $\mathbb{R}^2$ defined by
$$
   s_1(x)=|x_1-x_2|,\quad s_2(x)=|x_1+x_2|,\quad\forall x=(x_1,x_2)\in \mathbb{R}^2
$$
We have a neighborhood  $U$ of  $(0,0)$ is
$$
 U=\cap_{j\in\{1,2\}}\{x;\ s_j(x)\le \epsilon_j \}
$$
where $\epsilon_j >0$.
Then, a neighborhood of $x$ is $x+U$, $x\in\mathbb{R}^2$.

We define a subset  $G\subset \mathbb{R}^2$ an open set if $G$ contains a neighborhood of each of its point.

It is easy to show that the collection $\tau_2$ of all open sets defined above forms a topology on $\mathbb{R}^2$ and Hausdorff space

How to show that the topology $\tau_1$ is identical with $\tau_2$?

Comment: You can invoke the general result that any two Hausdorff topologies on a finite-dimensional space are the same.

Comment: @QuantumSpace: the general result that you cite must include some qualification. E.g., consider the standard topology and the discrete topology.

Comment: Try a change of basis so that $s_1((y_1, y_2)) = y_1$ and $s_2((y_1, y_2)) = y_2$. The new topology then becomes the sup norm topology, which is the same as the Euclidean topology.

Comment: @RobArthan Yes, you are right. I meant topologies compatible with the linear structure, which is obvious here since both topologies come from norms.